# OneToOne in Hibernate - Unknown "mappedBy"

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I'm exercising with hibernate and I'm failing since hours in implementing a OneToOne relationship. I read a lot of answers on stackoverflow and went through 2 tutorials (mkyong and some other guy), but I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

I tried a lot of things, but I always end up with the same exception (`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: ch.myapp.model.Employee.office, referenced property unknown: ch.myapp.model.Office.EMPLOYEES`)

I would be really glad if someone could give me a hint where the problem lies.

I'm using [this database scheme](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/img/documentation/sample-database/ClassicModelsDBSchema.jpg) and I try to implement a 1:1 between Office and Employee (I know that this doesn't make a lot of sense).

**Employee.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEENUMBER")
    private Integer employeeNumber;
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "EXTENSION")
    private String extension;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "JOBTITLE")
    private String jobTitle;
    @Column(name = "OFFICECODE")
    private String officeCode;

    // ACHTUNG, Test "EmployeeDataAccesTest -> loadEmployee()" greift auf einen
    // Null-Wert zurück. Null kann keinem primitiven Wert zugeordnet werden.
    @Column(name = "REPORTSTO")
    private Integer reportsto;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "EMPLOYEES", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Office office;

//Getters and setters without annotations...
}
```

**Office.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OFFICES")
public class Office {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OFFICECODE")
    private String officeCode;
    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESSLINE1")
    private String addressLine1;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESSLINE2")
    private String addressLine2;
    @Column(name = "STATE")
    private String state;
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;
    @Column(name = "POSTALCODE")
    private String postalCode;
    @Column(name = "TERRITORY")
    private String territory;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OFFICECODE")
    private Employee employee;

//Getters and setters without annotations...
}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
l version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:/home/dev/dev/git/TestBusiness/myDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="ch.myapp.model.Office"/>
        <mapping class="ch.myapp.model.Employee"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is the Stacktrace I get (first couple of lines):

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: ch.myapp.model.Employee.office, referenced property unknown: ch.myapp.model.Office.EMPLOYEES
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1659)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1634)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at ch.myapp.HibernateManager.getSessionFactory(HibernateManager.java:44)
    at ch.myapp.HibernateManager.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction(HibernateManager.java:24)
    at ch.myapp.dataaccess.EmployeeDataAccess.load(EmployeeDataAccess.java:18)
    at ch.myapp.dataaccess.OfficeDataAccessTest.shouldLoadOffice(OfficeDataAccessTest.java:24)
```

Comment: did you check whether the package name is "ch.myapp.model.Employee"

Comment: @srikanthr Uhm, the package name is "ch.myapp.model". Hm, I wonder if that's the problem.

Answer (score 7):

1.Make sure the **attribute** is as follows:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Office office;
```

2. Make sure the **getter** is as follows:

   `public Office getOffice() {
       return office;
   }`

**mappedBy** annotations refers to attribute names, not column names. Also since attributes are private, hibernate access them through their getter/setter, thus you need it to follow convention (get,Camel Case, etc)

Answer (score 5):

you had wrong mappedBy value in Employee.class it should be the following:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Office office;
```

Comment: @TrudleR than edit your question with what error pops up than - he is correct and that should work. Also, paste getters you use for those two relevant properties. There might be something fishy with mapping "OFFICECODE" twice, once as Id and once not, but that's another story

Answer (score 4):

the value of `mappedBy` must be same as the attribute's name in referenced class including its case.

for instance,

If the attribute's name is `employee`, you have to write exactly `employee`.

If the attribute's name is `employeE`, you have to write exactly `employeE`.

(getter function's name is proper)

Answer (score 1):

Check if both your entities are in `persistence.xml`